# Ada + POlyORB: lookup failed in the naming server

Tags: ada

I'm trying to build a distributed application in Ada using the DSA and after hours of trial and error I finally managed to get it to compile correctly. However, now I have problems with the naming server.

My application is composed of two partitions: one hosts a simple RCI unit, the other is the client that calls the RCI unit. After compilation, I start up the name server by calling `po_con_naming` and it comes up correctly

I then start the executable that corresponds to my RCI partition, and here is where the problem pops up. On the name server console, these lines appear, about one every second:

```
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
cosnaming.namingcontext: look for "AAAA polyorb.dsa_p.partitions        RCI;"
```

After that the RCI partition executable prints:

```
raised SYSTEM.RPC.COMMUNICATION_ERROR : lookup of RCI polyorb.dsa_p.partitions failed
```

And closes

So basically, the naming server gets contacted, but it can't find that partition. Please note that that partition is not part of my application, I'm assuming it's something the po_gnatdist compiler adds, but I can't understand what is failing here.

I didn't post code because it's a bit big, if it's needed to debug this let me know and I'll try to trim it down to a smaller sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found the problem shortly after posting.

In my DSA configuration file I was designating the "main" procedure as the one in the client. Turns out, it needs to be in the "server", ie: in the partition that exposes the RCI packages.